# Flutter driver - enter text into field that is off screen

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, flutterdriver

I am trying to write an integration test for a screen with multiple TextFormFields. For each test, I am simply:

1. Tapping the text field
2. Entering some text
3. Checking if the text exists in the text field.

Using Flutter driver, the following works well for each TextFormField:

```
final myTextField = find.byValueKey('TextField');

test('Enter text into text field', () async {
   await driver.tap(myTextField);
   await driver.enterText('Hello world');
   await driver.waitFor(find.text('Hello world'));
 });
```

However for any TextFormFields that are off-screen (ie. not visible / outside of the viewport), the test fails with a timeout error.

I tried adding `scrollIntoView()` to the tests to tell Flutter Driver to scroll until the field is in the viewport. Below is an example:

```
final myTextField = find.byValueKey('TextField');

test('Enter text into text field', () async {
   await driver.scrollIntoView(myTextField); // Added
   await driver.tap(myTextField);
   await driver.enterText('Hello world');
   await driver.waitFor(find.text('Hello world'));
 });
```

However the tests continue to fail with a timeout error:

```
FlutterDriver: tap message is taking a long time to complete...
00:39 +0 -1: My screen: Enter text into text field [E]

  TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Test timed out after 30 seconds.
```

How do I test TextFormFields that are outside of the viewport?

---

**Update:** I've found that using `scrollUntilVisible()` is preferred to `scrollIntoView()`, as the element may not yet have been rendered yet and therefore cannot be found (see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/scrolling).

`scrollUntilVisible()` successfully auto-scrolls the screen and finds the element that was off screen. However, once found, the screen automatically jumps back up to the top for some reason, making the element off-screen again. What's going on?

```
final myTextField = find.byValueKey('TextField');
final myListView = find.byValueKey('ListView');

test('Enter text into text field', () async {
     await scrollUntilVisible(
     myListView,
     finder,
     // To scroll down the list, provide a negative value to dyScroll.
     // Ensure that this value is a small enough increment to
     // scroll the item into view without potentially scrolling past it.
     //
     // To scroll through horizontal lists, provide a dxScroll
     // property instead.
     dyScroll: -100
   );

   await driver.tap(myTextField);
   await driver.enterText('Hello world');
   await driver.waitFor(find.text('Hello world'));
 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question more thoroughly ?

Comment: @ChinkySight Ok, I have added some extra details now.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to re-create your case and was able to run a driver test successfully that entered text in non-visible textfield on screen using `ScrollIntoView()` method. Here's what I did for demo:

- In `main.dart`, had series of `textformfields` having unique `key` for each, wrapped inside `Column` which was wrapped in `SingleChildScrollView`:

[image]

When we scroll down, you'll see the last textfield with `hintText` `Last TextField` which is not visible when screen launches.

[image]

For this setup, wrote two driver tests to tap and enter text as below:

```
test('Enter text into first text field', () async {
      await driver.tap(myTextField);
      await driver.enterText('Hello world');
      await driver.waitFor(find.text('Hello world'));
    });

    test('Enter text into last text field', () async {
      await driver.scrollIntoView(myTextField21);
      await driver.tap(myTextField21);
      await driver.enterText('Hello');
      await driver.waitFor(find.text('Hello'));

    });
```

Which successfully entered text in last textfield after scrolling into it first.

[image]

Hope this helps.